# How can I make my lines line up, move less then 1px?

Tags: jasper-reports

In a subreport I have line and I can't line this up perfectly with surrounding elements, even moving it just 1 px each time. It's seems to always 1/2 a pixel off.

Is it possibile to move it less than 1 px?

Comment: In my opinion you should edit the jrxml directly for precise positioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You can't

I also find this annoying when trying to get pixel perfect lines to line up, even if I understand the reason, lineWidth/2 = int (px)). My work around is to **not** use lines but instead borders on text box.

Example to show the problem and the solution, 2 connected lines (lineWidth=2px vs text box with borders)

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Lines" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3f1fba4c-298d-4b77-bf79-04798f7724f3">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="1" uuid="1b773b6e-63d4-4003-b145-edbff21586cf">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#FF0400"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1" height="50" uuid="675afe9c-5fee-4cb8-9747-9ca3524e1a4d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#FF0400"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="50" height="50" uuid="7c52df48-a692-47fa-a3bf-fca0130785fa">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#FF0400"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#FF0400"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: This is quite annoying because my lines lenght depends on the number of columns my subreport returns. I don't see how i could do this with textboxes

Comment: @razorvla if you can show a [mcve], something I can run easily and I can try to show you how.